# Using restricted maximum likelihood on marginal residuals

Tags: mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, reml

In a mixed-model setting, I want to estimate the variance components and the pertaining random effects of a random-intercept/random-slope model. The coefficients of the fixed effects have already been determined in a previous iteration step. Thus, I would like to fit a mixed-model on the marginal residuals $\hat{y} - X\hat{\beta}$.

In R, using the function *lmer*, this can be achieved by using an offset

```r
lmer_0 <- lmer(formula = y ~ offset(eta) + 
           (xij_1|id), data = data_0)
```

where 'eta' corresponds to  $X\hat{\beta}$.

However, the variance components of the random intercepts and the random slopes will now be biased, since restricted maximum likelihood uses

$$
\frac{1}{2} \log \left|\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime} \boldsymbol{V}(\vartheta)^{-1} \boldsymbol{X}\right|,
$$

which includes the fixed-effect design matrix $X$, which is not provided by the function call. This problem can be solved by including all fixed-effects as covariates, resulting in their coefficients being estimated, too. However, this significantly increases the computation time and I am not interested in the fixed-effect estimates.

Is their a way to solve this problem, possibly using some other function than *lmer*?

Comment: Measuring the performance and accuracy of two-stage methods is hard in general.  It would be better for formulate a full, single, model.

Comment: Hello Prof. Harrel. Thank you very much for your quick reply. The mixed model is supposed to be part of a gradient-boosting algorithm. The fixed effects I want to update incrementally separately from the random effects in each iteration in a standard boosting fashion. The random effects I don't want to update incrementally, but by re-estimating them completely anew at every iteration. Therefore, formulating a single model is not really possible.

Comment: Just be sure that standard one-step statistical modeling is not better for your particular needs.